# blazor api override User.name to get login or preferred_username

Tags: c#, authentication, blazor, identity

I have Blazor wasm + api project
auth using oauth on external serwer
auth works fine, i add token using clasic
`CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler:AuthorizationMessageHandler`

and now in API i need to have username whi did request post/get

so i can do

```
 var username = User.Identity.Name
```

but this give me  `name + surname` and i need `login`

i searched claims and found that i can do

```
  var username = User.Claims.Where(p=>p.Type== "preferred_username").First().Value;
```

and this works fine
but is there better way ? for example to override this `User.Identity.Name`  so it returns this `preferred_username` ?

thanks and regards